# Does the BEGINS formula work in an HTML Email template?

Tags: formula, email-template, html

I have an email template in which I need to display a person's role, but I need to determine whether the role starts with a vowel (eg Accountant) so that I can correctly display 'a' or 'an' before it in the sentence. Eg:

'I, as **an** Accountant.... or
'I, as **a** Lawyer...

Currently I have:
I, as {!IF(BEGINS(object__c.Role__c,'A'),'an','a')} {!object__c.Role__c}, ...

but it's not returning anything for me. Can I use BEGINS here or do I need to use something else?

Here's what I see when I just put the options into the template. Neither the BEGINS or LEFT options return anything?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEXT(anyField) returns null in HTML email templates;

**Options**

- Can you use a VF email template instead? You have much more expressive power in formulas
- Create a formula field on your object `RoleAsText__c = TEXT(Role__c)` and refer to `{!...RoleAsText__c ...}` in your email template formulas

Comment: I would prefer not to have to go into that work just to accommodate whether to use 'a' or 'an', so was hoping I could just use a formula. So are you saying that I cannot use the LEFT or BEGINS formula function on a picklist field?

Comment: @Irene Shoot. I'm pretty sure cropredy's right. The basic template merge feature is kind of useless. It's been a while since I've used it, so it's probably right.

Comment: @Irene - yes, I placed a simple `{!TEXT(Contact.FirstName)}` in an email template and saw that the result is NULL. Picklists require wrapping with `TEXT` to inspect the characters so you are out of luck.  It is for reasons like this that I tend to use VF email templates so I'm not hamstrung nor reduced to hacks

Comment: I was considering using a VF template, but then I can't set the recipient to my custom field in my custom object. The recipient is neither a contact, lead or user, but a name and email address on my custom object. It looks like my only option therefore is to create a formula field on my object to determine the role. Not ideal.